# Finding items from an array of objects based on a selected item value in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
var array = [
    { name:"string123", value:"this", other: "that" },
    { name:"string2", value:"this", other: "that" },
    { name:"string12", value:"ths", other: "that" },
];
```

And now I have a string like 'string12'. Now with this string the output I want is to find the items that contains this string which is like:

```
var array = [
    { name:"string123", value:"this", other: "that" },
    { name:"string12", value:"ths", other: "that" },
];
```

Here's what I have tried:

```js
const search = (nameKey, myArray) => {
  for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    var newArr = [];
    if (myArray[i].name.slice(0, nameKey.length + 1) === nameKey) {
      newArr.push(myArray[i]);
    }
    return newArr;
  }

}

var array = [
  { name:"string123", value:"this", other: "that" },
  { name:"string2", value:"this", other: "that" },
  { name:"string12", value:"ths", other: "that" },
];

var resultObject = search("string12", array);
console.log(resultObject);
```

But my solution is returning a blank array. Where am I going wrong with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following things went wrong in your implementation:

1. Move initialization outside the `for` loop.
2. You don't need +1 when doing `.slice()`.
3. Return statement `return newArr` should be outside the `for` loop.

```
const search = (nameKey, myArray) => {
    var newArr = [];
  
  for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    if (myArray[i].name.slice(0, nameKey.length) === nameKey) {
      newArr.push(myArray[i]);
    }
  }
    return newArr;
}

var array = [
  { name:"string123", value:"this", other: "that" },
  { name:"string2", value:"this", other: "that" },
  { name:"string12", value:"ths", other: "that" },
];

var resultObject = search("string12", array);
console.log(resultObject);
```

Comment: +1. To provide a new solution is easy. But sometimes what OP want is an explanation of what he is doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`String#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes):

```js
const arr = [ { name:"string123", value:"this", other: "that" }, { name:"string2", value:"this", other: "that" }, { name:"string12", value:"ths", other: "that" } ];

const res = arr.filter(({ name }) => name.includes('string12'));

console.log(res);
```

You can use [`String#startsWith`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) instead of `includes` if you only need to check if the name starts with the string.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with `Array.filter` and `startsWith` function ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith)). If you want to check `string12` anywhere in `name` use `includes` instead of `startsWith`

```js
var array = [
    { name:"string123", value:"this", other: "that" },
    { name:"string2", value:"this", other: "that" },
    { name:"string12", value:"ths", other: "that" },
];

const filtered = array.filter(item => item.name.startsWith("string12"));

console.log(filtered);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're just searching for string at start then removing + 1 form **myArray[i].name.slice(0,nameKey.length + 1)**  will work for you then only it will match the exact string you're searching for and also you have to declare newArr above the loop so it can hold the value and return it after the loop ends hope it helps

```
    const search = (nameKey, myArray)=> {
    var newArr = [];
    for (var i=0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
        if (myArray[i].name.slice(0,nameKey.length) === nameKey) {
            newArr.push(myArray[i]);
        }
    }
    return newArr;
}

var array = [
    { name:"string123", value:"this", other: "that" },
    { name:"string2", value:"this", other: "that" },
    { name:"string12", value:"ths", other: "that" },
    { name:"string1234567", value:"ths", other: "that" },
];

var resultObject = search("string12", array);
console.log(resultObject);
```

You can also use modern syntax for this problem

```
const search = (nameKey, myArray) => {
  return myArray.filter(elem => elem.name.startsWith(nameKey));
};

var array = [
  { name: "string123", value: "this", other: "that" },
  { name: "string2", value: "this", other: "that" },
  { name: "string12", value: "ths", other: "that" },
];

var resultObject = search("string12", array);
console.log(resultObject);
```